# What do you call the tip on an umbrella?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call the tip on an umbrella?

Yes, since *tip* means 'the usually pointed end of something', I know that tip itself can be used for — i.e. umbrella tip —, but I'm looking for a single word which has that meaning?

---

[image]

Comment: I'd call it "the pointy thing that the people carrying the umbrella always seem to forget, while pinching everyone walking beside/behind them with it". Although, of course, the other answers are much more polite (and appropriate).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that is easily found online - general reference.

Answer (score 9):

The spike at the end is called the ***End***. It can have a ***ferrule*** right at the end or be left unadorned.

[image: Parts of an umbrella]

[Richtom80](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Richtom80) at the [English language Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/) | [Link to image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Parts_of_an_Umbrella.svg)

Comment: Nice find, +1, trust an Englishman to know the jargon of umbrellas :).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://www.everumbrella.com/Umbrella-Parts--Diagram.php) it is called a *finial* or *ferrule*